# ¿Cómo sobreescribir archivos .php en el fichero functions.php del tema hijo de WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy tratando de sustituir archivos que se incluyen en el fichero functions.php del tema padre:

```
require_once (TEMPLATEPATH. '/functions/page_header_image.php');
```

¿Cómo puedo sustituir este archivo desde el fichero functions.php del tema hijo?

Comment: Pues no lo llames. Comenta la línea y listo. Solo que si tu tema necesita funciones o métodos que están definidos en ese archivo, tu tienes que proporcionarlos en otro.

Comment: La cuestión es que cada que se actualice el tema padre, tendré que comentar la línea, lo ideal es sobreescribirlo desde el tema hijo, saludos.

Comment: Sí está bien escrito, el tema padre ofrecerá medios de cambiar funcionalidades en `page_header_image.php` a través de hooks. Quizá enseñando el código que deseas cambiar se pueda encontrar manera de intervenir directamente allí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo hay que sobreescribir el archivo en el directorio del tema hijo, osea, dentro de tu **Child Theme** deberías tener un directorio llamado `functions/` y dentro de este un archivo llamado **page_header_image.php**, y si no quieres que el código escrito en él tenga efecto, sencillamente lo dejas en blanco.

Me gustaría saber qué tema usas, pues es probable que esté algo desfasado, pues `TEMPLATEPATH` y `STYLESHEETPATH` están obsoletas https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18298.

En fin, la manera correcta de incluir un archivo es usando la función 
[`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @Roger, el template que uso es: [enlace](https://themeforest.net/item/456-industry-repair-tools-shop-construction-building-renovation-wp-theme/6147589).